# How do you get a User Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Once a user is authenticated and authorized, the application can get information about the user by using the User object’s Identity property. The Identity property returns an object that includes the user name and role information.

Below is the code snippet which I have used to understand the concept:-

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
 Label1.Text = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString();
 Label2.Text = User.Identity.Name;
 Label3.Text = User.Identity.AuthenticationType;
}
```

Is there any other way to get the User Identity?

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you need another way to get it?

Comment: I was just doing a search to find the other way out. Although this is working for me. I was just enquiring if I can find some other way too...

Comment: If you just want the users Identity.. from an ASP.NET WebPage when the Page_Load is called create a string[] and do something like the following string strRawUser = Page.User.Identity.Name;
Then from there strRawUser[0] will have the Domain and strRawUser[1] will have the users login id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please clarify if you are wanting something like the following below..

If you just want the users Identity.. from an ASP.NET WebPage when the Page_Load is called create a string[] and do something like the following

```
string strRawUser = Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

Then from there strRawUser will have something like "DomainName\UserName"
So you need to Split the string into an stringArray and get the string[1] value like this

```
string[] strRawUserSplitter = Page.User.Identity.Name.Split("\\");
Label2.Text = strRawUserSplitter[1]
```

Comment: Glad I could provide you with a simple solution happy coding :)

Comment: Thanx a lot DJ KRAZE...happy coding to you too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the current user identity using Principal Object.