# Get Domain Credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, ntlm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Impersonation from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559719/windows-impersonation-from-c-sharp)
>   [How do you get a User Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410953/how-do-you-get-a-user-identity)

I have an application that pulls data from intranet systems and displays it to employees. The issue I have now is that everything is ran under my credentials, so theres no way to track who makes changes, etc.

How can I get the domain credentials from the person who is access the script? Its ASP.Net with C# (.Net 4.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to [impersonate the identity](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158#3)  of the current user. See examples #1 or #3.

Comment: That did it. Also ran into getting a 500 error when setting impersonate to true, so I used this:
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t113662-internal-server-error.html